# wp_title() shows 404 - installation outside WP

Tags: wp-title

`wp_title()` from theme's `header.php` shows "Page not found". Also the `body_class` displays the word "error404".

- the WP blog is installed on site.com/blog/
- a post is rendered outside WP installation, more specific on wildcard-subdomain.site.com/articles/post-slug

I added on page:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require( ROOT_DIR . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

- i added `get_header()`, `get_footer()` and it works fine
- in the theme's `functions.php` file I added  `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`
- The hooks work fine, also plugins are loading

Why doesn't the post title display?

Answer (score 1):

You could do an outside query instead.

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wpdb;
require(ROOT_DIR.'/blog/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');

get_header();

try{
    $args = array('post_type' => array('post'), 'posts_per_page' => -1);
    $qry = null;
    $qry = new WP_Query($args);
    if($qry->have_posts()){
        while($qry->have_posts()){
            $qry->the_post();
            $theTitle = get_the_title();
            print $theTitle.'<br>';
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }else{
        print 'no records found';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to show the title and have a proper body_class, wordpress has to parse first the url and find out what type of page is being referenced in geenral and which specific page it is. You can setup the `$_SERVER` variable with url data that will make sense for wordpress.

.... or do an explicit query to set everything as in @dan's answer